# How do you search and replace anything beyond an equal sign

Tags: regex, eclipse, replace

We have a property file (name, value key pairs) and would like to replace everything beyond the equal sign = with nothing. How do I do that?

```
label.one=One
label.two=Two
```

Post replacement, I would want

```
label.one=
label.two=
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a regexp: replace `=.*$` by `=` (with CTRL-F and regexp checked)